# Plotly: How to adjust annotation text angle for rectangles using `add_vrect()`?

Tags: python, annotations, plotly, plotly-python, angle

In the following MWE:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_vrect(
    x0 = 0,
    x1 = 1,
    opacity = .25,
    line_width = 0,
    fillcolor = 'black',
    annotation_text = 'Hola, cómo estás? Este es un texto muy largo y va mejor en vertical',
)
fig.show()
```

how can I rotate the text, like this?

[image]

I have tried adding `textangle = -90` as an argument to `add_vrect` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you'll have to use `annotation_textangle` like this:

fig.add_vrect(x0=0.9, x1=2, annotation_text="vertical rectangle",
annotation_position="top left",
annotation_textangle = 90)

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9)
fig.add_vrect(x0=0.9, x1=2, annotation_text="vertical rectangle",
              annotation_position="top left",
              annotation_textangle = 90,
             )
fig.show()
```